# Return a json of multiple key-value pairs instead of list of single-paired key-value jsons

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

Currently my query looks like follows and returns the results below:

```
select
    c.id as company_id,
    json_agg(json_build_object(ds.statement_ref, value)) as financials
from
    st.data_statements ds
    join st.company_data cd on ds.company_datum_id = cd.id
    join st.companies c on cd.company_id = c.id
where
    c.id = 61
group by
    c.id
```

The result looks like this:

```
61  [{"in31" : "0.0"}, {"in32" : "145.8"}, {"in34" : "134.0"}]
```

How do I modify the query above to return all key pair values within the same JSON object (rather then a list of jsons)? Expected output:

```
61  {"in31" : "0.0", "in32" : "145.8", "in34" : "134.0"}
```

Comment: I think you want `json_object_agg ()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
json_agg(json_build_object(ds.statement_ref, value)) as financials
```

with

```
json_object_agg(ds.statement_ref, value) as financials
```

Comment: Thanks. Got lost in all the new functions Postgres introduced for jsons.